# XPages: help required building versioning functionality in CMS app

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to build a versioning system for our current internal CMS.  The way it works is that a new document is created when the users click on the edit button, modifying that new draft document.  When hitting the "Publish" button, I need to create a copy of the currently published doc and move the draft to the currently published document, as we need to keep the same UNID as there are potentially links in other pages that point to that UNID (URLs used for links contains the UNID).

Because of the way rich text is handled (not on disk until the full JSF cycle is completed - thanks to Stephen Wissel for the tip), it is a bit more complex than the logic that was applied in LotusScript.

Any hints on what logic to use? What events should be used, or should I just take a completely different approach, such as keeping the UNID of the draft I want to publish in a session scope variable and have an XAgent/page do the swapping of doc content????

I'm out of ideas here...    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation Wiki on openntf](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/xpages%20documentation%20wiki)

The Wiki has version control, hope it helps.

Comment: Ruud, the wiki's version control is not working from the web: it creates a new version on every save.  that is not quite what I'm looking for.  I since then found a solution to my problem and will post asnswer shortly, as soon as the code is clean enough ;)  I used code in an xAgent/xPage to do whatI wanted to do, basically...